# How to fetch data from PostgreSQL using PHP

Tags: php, psql

I am unable to fetch data from PostgreSQL in PHP. Every time I ran a query it returns NULL.

My query:

```
$psql = new psql('localhost','database','user','password');

$psq = pg_query("SELECT * FROM students");
$result = pg_fetch_row($psq);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What does the `psql` class do? I don't think that's part of core PHP.

Comment: Please let me know which one you are referring?

Comment: The one in the first line of your code, where you call `new psql()`. What does that class do?

Comment: I have seen it somewhere to connect to psql server

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [documentation for basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php), which should help you get on the right track.

Comment: Why don't you use PDO for this?

Comment: because I get an error using connection PDO

Comment: @Andreas this is the error : is the server running on host and accepting tcp/ip connections on port 5432? and I don't want to configure my serevr

Comment: Is postgres running on the server? port 5432 is the default port on which postgres is accepting connections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with the database connection. Try to use `pg_last_error()` to see what is going on. Here are some examples:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname='database';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'password';

    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=$dbhost dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpass")
        or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM students';
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Error message: ' . pg_last_error());

    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }

    pg_free_result($result);
    pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

And with PDO:

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbname='database';
        $dbuser = 'user';
        $dbpass = 'password';

        $connection = new PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM students';

        foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row) {
            var_dump($row);
        }

        $connection = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error message: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much can you please answer this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156061/fetching-data-from-postgresql-error